# How do you extend a Django project root HTML file in project apps?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Below is the structure of my Django App:

```
Project/
    static/
    App1/
    App2/
    App3/
    ...
```

So I have a Django project, and I want to keep the HTML/CSS styling uniform across the apps in the project.

How does one go about extending a HTML template residing in the Project folder from each of these apps?

I have only been successful extending HTML templates within App folders for each respective App.

My project settings has static files set to be located in "/static/"

Comment: templates don't need to be served like static files (becuase your users shouldn't be able to access them. your apps will use them to render an HttpResponse). CSS and js files - those are client side code, the user side has to be able to download them as is, and the browser is responsible to run them. What's getting you confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your project-common templates in `Project/templates` and add the `/path/to/Project/templates` to your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting in your `settings.py` file. prepend the root to everything else, so it gets searched first:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/path/to/Projects/templates",
    #other dirs ...
)
```

Then you go extend it from your application templates as usual:

```
{# App1/templates/App1/template1.html #}
{% extends "template_in_project_root.html" %}
...
```

[the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs)

Comment: So I can have multiple paths in TEMPLATE_DIRS?

Comment: Sure, they get searched in their order.

Comment: defining a ROOT_DIR and doing `os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'templates')` is better.